# How to set values from the onTimeSet() method using callback?

Tags: android, interface, callback, timepicker

I have this method in the `TimePickerApp` class:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int minute, int second) {
    this.timerMinute = minute;
    this.timerSecond = second;
}
```

I want to set the values of minutes and seconds from my main class when the user press the set button of the `TimePicker`, that is when the `onTimeSet` method is called.

I have get methods for minute and second in the `TimePickerApp` class.

I want to implement callback using interface, my doubt is how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TimePickerDialog with a different OnTimeSetListener callback so that you can handle the event with whatever object you choose.